# ConstraintViolationException: NOT NULL when using Spring, HSQL and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I get a NOT NULL constraint violation exception when trying to insert an object of type Individual in the DB. I use hsql version 2.3.2. I let hibernate generate the DB tables for me.
In the normal code (where I use an SQLServer Database) everything works fine.

This is my Individual Object, where the ID is generated by the database and is the primary key of the table.

Individual object:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name="INDIVIDUALS")
public class Individual {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name="INDIVIDUAL_ID")
     private long id;
```

In the HealthCareProfessional object, there is link towards the primary key of this Individual object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="HEALTHCARE_PROFESSIONALS")
public class HealthCareProfessional {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name="HEALTHCARE_PROFESSIONAL_ID")
     private long id;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "INDIVIDUAL_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
     private Individual individual;

     ...
```

The application context where I define the entityManagerFactory looks like this:

```
 <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />

 <bean id="emf"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/persistence-unittest.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testingSetup"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <!-- Create the database, please -->
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="jpaVendorAdaptor"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
 </bean>
```

My persistence xml is defined as follows:

```
 <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="testingSetup">
        <!-- The autodetection only works if the classes are packaged as a JAR. Doesn't work for unit tests. Go figure -->
        <class>be.healthconnect.pwg.domain.individual.HealthCareProfessional</class>
        <class>be.healthconnect.pwg.domain.individual.Individual</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

This is my unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = {"classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml"})
@Transactional
public class IndividualDaoTest {

    private static final String SSIN_JELLE= "81062205558";
    private static final String NIHII = "123";

    @Autowired
    private IIndividualDao individualDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Individual individual = buildIndividual(SSIN_JELLE);
        individualDao.addIndividual(individual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetIndividualsBySSIN() throws Exception {

        final List<Individual> individuals = individualDao.getIndividuals(SSIN_JELLE);
        Assert.assertNotNull(individuals);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, individuals.size());
        Individual individual = individuals.get(0);
        Assert.assertNotNull(individual);
    }
```

And this is the error message I got:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10143 table: HEALTHCARE_PROFESSIONALS column: INDIVIDUAL_ID
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1360)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1294)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:860)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.persist(Unknown Source)
at be.healthconnect.pwg.data_access.dao.impl.IndividualDao.addIndividual(IndividualDao.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.addIndividual(Unknown Source)
at be.healthconnect.pwg.data_access.dao.impl.IndividualDaoTest.setUp(IndividualDaoTest.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I really don't understand why hsql doesn't use the generated values for the ID...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `nullable = false` on the line `@JoinColumn(name = "INDIVIDUAL_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)`. Because at the time hibernate is making the link `ManyToOne` the ID of individual is not yet established, thus causing your error. If you really want extra protection from `null` values then use `@NotNull` outside of the `@JoinColumn`. The `nullable = false` inside the `@JoinColumn` creates the constraint on the database, while `@NotNull` will keep it at the object layer.